# Create json from bad xml

Tags: json, xml

I'm trying to figure out how I can take a broken xml file and turn it into a Json every time it updates? The xml file is broken so creating a functional Json isn't gonna work. I attempted to use jc --xml but the file is of course not formatted properly. I'm new to coding, trying to build my first application. It's been a crazy experience so far haha. There are two main things here. Nodes and Stations.
location of xml file /var/log/xlxd.xml where I want to generate the Json file /var/http/www/log/dashboard.json

The server is Debian

I have learned so much from this site, months and months of working on my first application. Some things to note that I have learned. Don't start a project without looking at the source of the data first haha.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Version>2.5.3</Version>
<XLX207  linked peers>
</XLX207  linked peers>
<XLX207  linked nodes>
<NODE>
    <Callsign>K9TON   B</Callsign>
    <IP>144.</IP>
    <LinkedModule>A</LinkedModule>
    <Protocol>YSF</Protocol>
    <ConnectTime>Thursday Thu Dec  7 00:33:05 2023</ConnectTime>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 22:39:02 2023</LastHeardTime>
</NODE>
<NODE>
    <Callsign>AG7AZ   B</Callsign>
    <IP>184.</IP>
    <LinkedModule>A</LinkedModule>
    <Protocol>YSF</Protocol>
    <ConnectTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 02:06:34 2023</ConnectTime>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 02:06:34 2023</LastHeardTime>
</NODE>
<NODE>
    <Callsign>K9TON   D</Callsign>
    <IP>98.</IP>
    <LinkedModule>C</LinkedModule>
    <Protocol>DCS</Protocol>
    <ConnectTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 04:07:43 2023</ConnectTime>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 04:07:43 2023</LastHeardTime>
</NODE>
<NODE>
    <Callsign>K9TON   B</Callsign>
    <IP>98.</IP>
    <LinkedModule>A</LinkedModule>
    <Protocol>YSF</Protocol>
    <ConnectTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 04:43:07 2023</ConnectTime>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 17:52:30 2023</LastHeardTime>
</NODE>
<NODE>
    <Callsign>NC1D    B</Callsign>
    <IP>68.</IP>
    <LinkedModule>C</LinkedModule>
    <Protocol>DCS</Protocol>
    <ConnectTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 11:05:38 2023</ConnectTime>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 22:21:38 2023</LastHeardTime>
</NODE>
<NODE>
    <Callsign>AG7AZ   B</Callsign>
    <IP>184.</IP>
    <LinkedModule>C</LinkedModule>
    <Protocol>DCS</Protocol>
    <ConnectTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 17:38:07 2023</ConnectTime>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 18:27:56 2023</LastHeardTime>
</NODE>
<NODE>
    <Callsign>N9MAS   B</Callsign>
    <IP>47.</IP>
    <LinkedModule>A</LinkedModule>
    <Protocol>YSF</Protocol>
    <ConnectTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 18:40:11 2023</ConnectTime>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 18:42:34 2023</LastHeardTime>
</NODE>
</XLX207  linked nodes>
<XLX207  heard users>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>NC1D    </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 22:39:02 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>AG7AZ   </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 22:37:33 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>K9TON   </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 22:31:53 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>NC1D     / JOEL</Callsign>
    <Via node>NC1D    B</Via node>
    <On module>C</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 22:21:40 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KA5JKI  </Callsign>
    <Via node>KA5JKI  B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 19:55:27 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KB9MQD  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 19:29:03 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KG4ISH  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 19:28:29 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KK7NLO  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 19:07:40 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KA5JKI  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 18:47:19 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>N9MAS   </Callsign>
    <Via node>N9MAS   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 18:42:34 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>AG7AZ    / ID52</Callsign>
    <Via node>AG7AZ   B</Via node>
    <On module>C</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 18:28:05 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KQ4DZY  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 14:02:10 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KO4ZUL  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 13:49:44 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>WH6GVN  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  9 00:54:04 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KG4ISH  </Callsign>
    <Via node>KG4ISH  B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Friday Fri Dec  8 23:57:25 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>K7TTM   </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Friday Fri Dec  8 21:50:40 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KK7OVZ  </Callsign>
    <Via node>KK7OVZ  B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Friday Fri Dec  8 18:44:11 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>AG7AZ   </Callsign>
    <Via node>AG7AZ   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Friday Fri Dec  8 18:44:00 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KI7ZNH  </Callsign>
    <Via node>KI7ZNH  B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Friday Fri Dec  8 17:45:03 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KO4ZUL  </Callsign>
    <Via node>KO4ZUL  B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Friday Fri Dec  8 16:50:46 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>DH1EM    / 4946</Callsign>
    <Via node>DH1EM   B</Via node>
    <On module>C</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Thursday Thu Dec  7 01:23:17 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KD0TGF  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Wednesday Wed Dec  6 22:03:31 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>NC1D    </Callsign>
    <Via node>NC1D    B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Wednesday Wed Dec  6 11:57:57 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>NC1D     / JOEL</Callsign>
    <Via node>NC1D    D</Via node>
    <On module>C</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Wednesday Wed Dec  6 11:12:21 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KF0MCM  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Monday Mon Dec  4 15:12:34 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>KB9MQD   / JACK</Callsign>
    <Via node>KB9MQD  Y</Via node>
    <On module>C</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Monday Mon Dec  4 02:18:01 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>K9TON    / TONY</Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   D</Via node>
    <On module>C</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Monday Mon Dec  4 02:05:48 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>IK2WBK  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Sunday Sun Dec  3 04:36:40 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
<STATION>
    <Callsign>PU2NMN  </Callsign>
    <Via node>K9TON   B</Via node>
    <On module>A</On module>
    <Via peer>XLX207  </Via peer>
    <LastHeardTime>Saturday Sat Dec  2 23:41:32 2023</LastHeardTime>
</STATION>
</XLX207  heard users>
```

I tried to research xml and understand that the xml generated is not properly formatted.

Comment: Are you generating the invalid XML? If so, first step is to fix it and get it to be valid XML.

Comment: The command `xmllint` is great for helping you identify what is wrong with your xml.

Comment: I'm not generating it, it is generated this way. I know what is wrong with the xml, it is not well formed. from my understanding, it needs to only have a single element? <root> </root>

Comment: If you don't have control over the file, and you made sure the people generating it can't fix it, and it's file which structure never really changes, it *may* be a solution to write a small parser, _or_ use a HTML parser (which may support custom elements and is more forgiving)

Comment: I wonder if this simply isn't XML, but some other SGML-based format.

Comment: Try to use an HTML or SGML parser. They are more tolerant to errors.

Comment: Stuff like `<Via node>KK7OVZ  B</Via node>` is not "broken XML". It's a data format that bears some passing resemblence to XML (like, it has angle brackets), but no XML tools are going to be of any use at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `sed` command to fix the sample AS IS

```
sed -re '1 s/.*/<&\n<root>/; :a; s/([^<]*<)([/]?[[:alnum:]]+) +([[:alnum:]]+.*>)/\1\2\3/; t a; $ s/.*/&\n<\/root>/' tmp.txt
```

Comment: This has got me the closest, trying to figure out now that I have the file cleaned up to make it a json file. The data is MUCH cleaner

Comment: Fixes the first problem. You can accept and /or upvote the asnwer and ask a different one if you find issues with the xml-json conversion,

Comment: This is the first line in the xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> when I run it with the sed it does this and I cant read it with jc. <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> its adding the < to the front of the file. I cant figure out how to remove that single char.

Comment: Removed it and got it. thank you!

Comment: if the XML declaration is correct then remove `<` from this part `1 s/.*/<&\n<root>/;`

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to fix the XML text and then you can parse it with a standard XML parser.

So, lets see whats wrong.

First off, I am assuming that the missing initial `<` character is just a cut-and-paste error.

Next is the fact that, as you indicate in a comment, the file does not have a "root" tag.  Inserting a `<root>` after the header and `</root>` at the end of the entire body is pretty straight forward.

Next is the improper attributes.  XML wants attributes to be key/value pairs,
and does not permit attributes in closing tags.  Since all of the attributes appear to be types for the tag, and no proper key/value pairs exist in the file, it would be simplest to just take all of these attributes like `linked peers` and convert them to `type="linked peers"` in the opening tags and remove all attributes from the closing tags.

The following code gets your file to pass `xmllint` for me.

```
import re

with open('input.xml', 'r') as fh:
    xml = fh.read()

xml = xml.replace('?>', '?><root>') + "</root>"

bad_opening_tag_re = r'<([^?][^ >]*) +([^>]+)>'
bad_opening_replacement = r'<\1 type="\2">'
bad_closing_tag_re = r'</([^ >]+) +([^>]+)>'
bad_closing_replacement = r'</\1>'

xml = re.sub(bad_opening_tag_re, bad_opening_replacement, xml)
xml = re.sub(bad_closing_tag_re, bad_closing_replacement, xml)

print(xml)
```

Comment: Good Afternoon! @Malcolm Thank you all so much for helping me get by here. I was able to pass and pipe to json with JC but still am getting stuck. The "Stations" that I really care about are all messed up and I'm unable to drill down when I do Stations to get Callsign, VIA, Module A or C, and LastHeard 
I was using jc trying to figure out how to clean up and get the following keys like this
<STATIONS>
.Callsign "K9TON"
.VIA "K9TON  B"
.Module "A"
.LastHeard "SUNDAY DECEMBER 10 17:43:10"

The "PEERS" isn't important and originally, I thought it was easy enough to just drill  down.

Comment: Maybe the comments about SGML parsers would be a better approach.  Perhaps you should look into Beautiful Soup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: In any case, if we have you past being able to parse the file into JSON at all, it might be best to open a new question about extracting the data.  This would give you the chance to give a concrete example of what "messed up" means, showing what you are getting and what you expect.